# Gaussian process regression not working in GPytorch and Scikit-learn, can't find suitable hyperparameters

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch, gaussian-process

This is a MWE of my problem, basically I want to find out the map between `qin` and `qout` using a Gaussian process and with that model trained, test the prediction of some validation data `qvalin` against `qvalout`.

`tensors.pt`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwYgEGqRRBPurIh8Vrb7f_lK-C9q0eQ_/view?usp=drive_link

I have left all default hyperparameters, except the learning rate. I haven't been able to lower the error below 92 % for either GPytorch or scikit-learn. I did some optimization but couldn't find a good combination of hyperparameters. Is there anything I am not doing correctly?

```py
import os
import glob
import pdb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
import torch
import gpytorch
import torch.optim as optim
from models_GP import MultitaskGPModel

def main():

    t1 = time.time()
    ten = torch.load('tensors.pt')
    qin = ten['qin']
    qout = ten['qout']
    qvalin = ten['qvalin']
    qvalout = ten['qvalout']
    # Rescaling
    qin_mean = qin.mean(dim=0)
    qin = qin - qin_mean
    qin = torch.divide(qin,qin.std(dim=0))
    qout_mean = qout.mean(dim=0)
    qout = qout - qout_mean
    qout = torch.divide(qout,qout.std(dim=0))
    qvalin_mean = qvalin.mean(dim=0)
    qvalin = qvalin - qvalin_mean
    qvalin = torch.divide(qvalin,qvalin.std(dim=0))
    qvalout_mean = qvalout.mean(dim=0)
    qvalout = qvalout - qvalout_mean
    qvalout = torch.divide(qvalout,qvalout.std(dim=0))
    qin = qin.reshape(-1, 1)
    #qout = qout.reshape(-1, 1)
    qvalin = qvalin.reshape(-1, 1)
    #qvalout = qvalout.reshape(-1, 1)

    # Scikit
    t1 = time.time()
    kernel = 1 * RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-2, 1e2))
    gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9)
    gaussian_process.fit(qin, qout)
    gaussian_process.kernel_

    mean_prediction, std_prediction = gaussian_process.predict(qvalin, return_std=True)
    print('Optimization time: {}'.format(time.time() - t1))

    plt.plot(qvalout, label=r"Validation set", )
    plt.plot(mean_prediction, label="Mean prediction")
    print(f'´Norm of diff: {100*np.linalg.norm(mean_prediction - qvalout.numpy()) / np.linalg.norm(qvalout)}%')
    plt.legend()
    _ = plt.title("Gaussian process regression using scikit")
    plt.savefig('scikit_.png', dpi=300)
    plt.show()

    # GPytorch
    num_tasks = 1
    likelihood = gpytorch.likelihoods.MultitaskGaussianLikelihood(num_tasks)
    model = MultitaskGPModel(qin, qout, likelihood)
    model.train()
    likelihood.train()
    opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1, betas=(0.9, 0.999),weight_decay=0)
    mll = gpytorch.mlls.ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(likelihood, model)
    training_iter = 20
    scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(opt, mode='min', factor=0.5, patience=100, verbose=True)
    for i in range(training_iter):
        opt.zero_grad()
        output = model(qin)
        loss = -mll(output, qout)
        loss.backward()
        print('Iter %d/%d - Loss: %.3f' % (i + 1, training_iter, loss.item()))
        opt.step()
    print('Optimization time: {}'.format(time.time() - t1))
    model.eval()
    likelihood.eval()
    f, (y1_ax) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 3))
    with torch.no_grad(), gpytorch.settings.fast_pred_var():
        test_x = qvalin
        test_x_out = qvalout
        predictions = likelihood(model(test_x))
        mean = predictions.mean
        lower, upper = predictions.confidence_region()
    y1_ax.plot(test_x_out.numpy(), label='Validation set')
    y1_ax.plot(mean.numpy(), label='Mean prediction')
    plt.legend()
    print(f'Norm of diff: {100 * np.linalg.norm(mean.numpy() - test_x_out.numpy()) / np.linalg.norm(test_x_out.numpy())}%')
    y1_ax.set_title('Gaussian Process regression using GPytorch)')
    plt.savefig('gpytorch_.png', dpi=300)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

models_GP.py

```py
class MultitaskGPModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super(MultitaskGPModel, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.MultitaskMean(
            gpytorch.means.ConstantMean(), num_tasks=1
        )
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.MultitaskKernel(
            gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel(), num_tasks=1, rank=1
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultitaskMultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)
```

[image]

[image]